# SQL Server store value during implicit transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having to restructure how an existing program deals with the database.

Before, I  was executing statements using odbc_php consecutively.
E.g
`SELECT [Value1] FROM TABLE` save to `$value1`
`INSERT INTO TABLE2 (VALUE2) VALUES ('$value1')`
`UPDATE TABLE SET [Value1] = '" . $value1 + 1 . "'`

You get the idea.

However I believe this way of running statements is causing conflict with 'other users' of the database.

My solution is to run the statements as an implicit transaction, however I require values being saved & reused during this transaction.

**so**, How do I save values from select statements in MSSQL?
(My skills are not ideal for MSSQL so any good tutorial or help document are apperciated)

Comment: Is this the totality of the fields within your database tables?  Your issue here is one of concurrency.  If you have multiple concurrent transactions hitting this, then there is nothing to stop two SELECT's from getting the same value1 from TABLE and which would result in an incorrect 'count' field in table2.

Comment: is concurrency the issue? as the statements are being individually executed via php odbc, they each hold their own transaction with the server. What I am aiming for is the statements as a whole transaction, where any issues with execution will result in total roll back

Comment: If you get two 'selects' against Table at the same time, they will both hold the same value for value1, as a SELECT will take a shared lock.  TABLE won't be locked until you perform the 'update' at which point it would be too late.

Comment: P.S. Please tell me your table is not really called `TABLE`

Comment: its not called table. unless my problem is code specific, I never upload existing code for questions, thus sample code with example names.

I see what your saying about the select issue. however with regards to my overall intention of the transaction, I don't think that issue will occur.

Comment: You may need to state what the conflict you were getting with other users was.

Comment: the conflict was between existing system software, and the program I am working with. the existing system that I'm having conflict with is proprietary, so having attempting 100% success is like walking backwards, blindfolded

Comment: If these answers are not what you need, then you need to specify what the conflict actually was, not just that it was happening.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with dealing with concurrent attempts to hit this sequence of commands.  Given that:

1. You want Table2 to have an entry for every incremented value1

and

2. You want Table1 to have value1 incremented by 1 every time this is executed.

In which case, I think you need to update Table1 first and then insert the original value prior to the update into table2, ensuring this remains consecutive:

```
DECLARE @UpdatedVal TABLE (InsertVal INT)

UPDATE Table1 
SET Value1 = (Value1 + 1)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Value1 
        INTO @InsertedVal

INSERT INTO Table2 (VALUE2)     
VALUES ((SELECT(InsertVal - 1) FROM @UpdatedVal)

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

One example:

```
declare @value int <\or any datatype>  --create a variable

select @value = value1
  from table  --set the value

insert into table2 (value2) values(@value) --insert it
```

Comment: I've just managed to use nested statements like the initial select inside the values field for the insert. worked well, but will give me a huge line to execute for what I require. i'll try your answer next